# Use a standard user account to download mails based on subscriptions

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I would like to know if is possible to use a standard user account to download mails based on subscriptions.

Background:

I have registered an App at Azure to have an App ID and a secret.
I use this credentials to create subscriptions for incoming mails. The notifications are send to a server which picks them up and downloads the mail content.

This all works fine but using the App ID and secret let me access all mailboxes and  may be a security issue.

To solve this I looked for two option but did not find much :

1. Limit access of the App id to certain mailboxes -> I think this is not possible
2. Create a kind of supper user and share all mailboxes with this user and use this user credentials to download the mail content based on the incoming notification

Has somebody tried solution 2 or could guide me to some documents?
As far as I know there is only an interactive user login possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect of using Client Credentials. Since you're authenticating your *application* instead of the user (you'll often hear this described as **app-only** vs **app+user**). When you authenticate an app, it is effectively a limited superuser ("limited" in terms of a superuser for the scope you consented).

The shared mailbox (often reffered to as a "Service Account") model works but it can be very fragile. You need to build a mechanism for re-authenticating this account when/if something goes sideways with your Access/Refresh tokens. You also need a mechanism for notifying you that something happened and a reliable process implemented so someone other than yourself can reset things 2 years from now. It also creates a support headache since you need to walk each user through sharing their mailbox (not exactly a familiar workflow for most users).

Instead of asking each user to go through the sharing workflow, I would ask them to authorize the application instead. You then set up the subscription using a separate app+user token for each user. This model does require some of the same mechanisms described above, but they're self-service focused and therefore less reliant on IT remembering how this was set up years down the road.

To do this you'll need to stand up a few elements:

- You need a web page that describes what is going on and presents a "Login with Microsoft" button that authenticates the user.
- You need a web page that the user will land on after completing the process (i.e. the "Thank You" page).
- You'll need to securely store the Refresh token for each user. This is less risky than it sounds since any malicious hacker would need *both* your Client Secret and the Refresh Token.
- You'll need a mechanism that captures failing or missing refresh tokens and sends an email to user altering them that they need to reauthenticate.

The workflow then looks something like this:

1. The user authenticates with your service
2. Using the initial Access Token you set up the subscription
3. The Refresh token is stored.
4. When a notification comes in, the service executes the Refresh token and retrieves the message(s).
5. A new refresh token was returned in Step 4 so you'll also need to replace the token you previously stored in Step 3.

I'd also consider using `/delta` when fetching messages. This allows you to get only the messages that have arrived since the last `/delta` was executed. It uses a "delta token" to track which messages have already been processed. You could store this token alongside the Refresh token (I'd also store the subscription metadata there as well).

This is a complex process and Stack Overflow isn't exactly the best forum for these. If you get tripped up going over this model, let me know and we can start a chat and go through this out-of-band of the Q&A (I can always update this answer if needed later).

Comment: Thank you ,Marc for your great answer.
My problem is that we migrate from Notes to Outlook and I need a system to cover the mail in databases which are not real user mail boxes and where no one looks active into .
There are about 50 Mail boxes and an interactive subscription is not real an option.
Also multiple tenants are not an option at the moment to divide personal mails from mail in data bases

Comment: A workaround may be to call a self-developed API returning access token based on mail box name so
no developer really knows the master secret.
About the shared mailbox (often reffered to as a "Service Account") model:
I think this is the solution to go because the token will be renewed at every download per mailbox so should not be an issue here ?
Are you aware of any code examples using a non-interactive login for this kind of access ?

Comment: A Service Account still requires an interactive authentication, you're basically creating a normal User Account without the actual human user. For a truly headless workflow, you really do need to use Client Credentials. There are a number of services on Azure (and elsewhere) to provide secure storage of the secret so that only an Admin or the app itself can access it. While not perfect, it at least ensures the secret isn't baked into the app and easily accessible by any developer with access to the code. In my env, devs use a separate developer tenant, isolating them from production.

Comment: For those rare cases where you need to work against production, you can create multiple secrets. I often have 1 secret for production and 1 for production debugging. I simply generate the secret when needed and delete it after the prod debugging is complete. This ensures my service keeps going without giving the devs indiscriminate access to any mailbox.